# SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure is slow

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am joining 3 different tables for an auto-complete functionality and it has to be quick. The suggestions have to come back nice and prompt. I need to look through 3 different fields for the answer with a `LIKE` operator. See details below.

```
DECLARE @Space AS CHAR(1) = ' ';

 SELECT TOP (@QuantityToReturn) * 
 FROM
     (SELECT
          C.CMPID, C.CMPNAME, C.CMPTHEIRCODE, AD.ADTOWN
      FROM COMPANY C
      JOIN [dbo].[COMPADDRESS] CA ON CA.CMPID = C.CMPID
      JOIN [dbo].[ADDRESS] ad ON AD.ADID = CA.ADID
      JOIN [dbo].SUPPLIER SUP ON C.CMPID = SUP.CMPID
      WHERE 
          (C.CMPID = @LoggedInUserId
           OR @LoggedInUserId = dbo.fnIsAParentCompanyOf(@LoggedInUserId, C.CMPID) 
           OR @LoggedInUserId = 12345)

      UNION 

      SELECT
          C.CMPID, C.CMPNAME, C.CMP_THEIRCODE, AD.ADTOWN
      FROM COMPANY C
      JOIN [dbo].[COMPADDRESS] CA ON ca.CMPID = C.CMPID
      JOIN [dbo].[ADDRESS] AD ON AD.ADID = CA.ADID
      JOIN [dbo].CUSTOMER CUS ON C.CMPID = CUS.CMPID AND CUS.CUSTISTHIS = 1
      WHERE 
          (C.CMPID = @LoggedInUserId
           OR @LoggedInUserId = dbo.fnIsAParentCompanyOf(@LoggedInUserId, C.CMPID) 
           OR @LoggedInUserId = 12345)
      ) AS Results
      WHERE 
          (CMPNAME + @Space + ADTOWN + @Space + CMPTHEIRCODE) LIKE '%' + @Query + '%'
```

The above code is slow (~ 9sec)

- If I use: `WHERE CMPNAME LIKE '%' + @Query + '%'` = quick;
- If I use: `WHERE ADTOWN LIKE '%' + @Query + '%'` = quick;
- If I use: `WHERE CMPTHEIRCODE LIKE '%' + @Query + '%'` = quick;

It is just when I concatenate them that goes slow?

Comment: You have not `sargable` predicate. Also you are using function calls. That's why it may be slow. Also you can consider changing `union` to `union all` if possible.

Comment: Instead of concatenating, are you able to `OR` them together? For example: `CMPNAME LIKE '%' + @Query + '%' OR ADTOWN LIKE '%' + @Query + '%' OR CMPTHEIRCODE LIKE '%' + @Query + '%'`

Comment: I tried the {OR} but it is still slow. Also it would not really fit requirements because they could search by company name and town which would then not return anything. UNION ALL did not help. The function call is fine. Explain the SARGABLE predicate suggestion please?

Comment: But your search relies on the user searching for exactly company name and town separated by a single space, what if they search for `Bob co, London`

Comment: You should pass in the query split in parts. Either ask your users in separate text boxes or use application logic to split the user's input. It seems to me more or less a matter of luck to find something with this approach. You  rely on the users to fill in their queries exactly the way you expect them...

Comment: @DavidG the user would be informed what is acceptable in the search box

Comment: Just to say that I have found a way to make it much quicker. The `ADDRESS` table had a `FK` in it of `ADDRESSTYPE`. I have now added that to the `JOIN` statement like so `JOIN [dbo].[ADDRESS] ad ON AD.ADID = CA.ADID AND AD.ADTID = 1` and it seems to have solved the issue. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try is this:

```
WHERE 
    LEN(@Query) <> LEN(REPLACE(@Query, CMPNAME, ''))

    AND (LEN(@Query) <> LEN(REPLACE(@Query, ADTOWN, ''))
         AND CHARINDEX(CMPNAME, @Query) = (CHARINDEX(ADTOWN, @Query) - 1 - LEN(CMPNAME)) 
        ) -- making sure that the value of ADTOWN comes after CMPNAME

    AND (LEN(@Query) <> LEN(REPLACE(@Query, CMPTHEIRCODE, ''))
         AND CHARINDEX(ADTOWN, @Query) = (CHARINDEX(CMPTHEIRCODE, @Query) - 1 - LEN(ADTOWN))
        ) -- making sure that the value of CMPTHEIRCODE comes after ADTOWN
```

I've tried re-implementing the logic of your 3 conditions to run on the parameters and not on the columns on which you have indexes. My assumption is that in this scenario the indexes will be used.

*PS: Small adjustments migth be needed when finding / substracting charindex's results, in case i made some mistakes in my calculations, but hopefully you got the idea.* - [SQLFiddle to validate that the CHARINDEX() comparisons are correct](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65687/6).

Also, I would recommend / try some additional changes to the top part of the query so in the end your script would look like this:

```
DECLARE @Space AS CHAR(1) = ' ';

SELECT TOP (@QuantityToReturn) *
FROM (
    SELECT C.CMPID
        ,C.CMPNAME
        ,C.CMPTHEIRCODE
        ,AD.ADTOWN
    FROM COMPANY C
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[COMPADDRESS] CA
        ON CA.CMPID = C.CMPID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ADDRESS] ad
        ON AD.ADID = CA.ADID
    WHERE (
            C.CMPID = @LoggedInUserId
            OR @LoggedInUserId = dbo.fnIsAParentCompanyOf(@LoggedInUserId, C.CMPID)
            OR @LoggedInUserId = 12345
            )
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [dbo].SUPPLIER SUP
            WHERE C.CMPID = SUP.CMPID
            )

    UNION

    SELECT C.CMPID
        ,C.CMPNAME
        ,C.CMP_THEIRCODE
        ,AD.ADTOWN
    FROM COMPANY C
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[COMPADDRESS] CA
        ON ca.CMPID = C.CMPID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ADDRESS] AD
        ON AD.ADID = CA.ADID
    WHERE (
            C.CMPID = @LoggedInUserId
            OR @LoggedInUserId = dbo.fnIsAParentCompanyOf(@LoggedInUserId, C.CMPID)
            OR @LoggedInUserId = 12345
            )
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [dbo].CUSTOMER CUS
            WHERE C.CMPID = CUS.CMPID
                AND CUS.CUSTISTHIS = 1
            )
    ) AS Results
WHERE LEN(@Query) <> LEN(REPLACE(@Query, CMPNAME, ''))
    AND (
        LEN(@Query) <> LEN(REPLACE(@Query, ADTOWN, ''))
        AND CHARINDEX(CMPNAME, @Query) = (CHARINDEX(ADTOWN, @Query) - 1 - LEN(CMPNAME))
        ) -- making sure that the value of ADTOWN comes after CMPNAME
    AND (
        LEN(@Query) <> LEN(REPLACE(@Query, CMPTHEIRCODE, ''))
        AND CHARINDEX(ADTOWN, @Query) = (CHARINDEX(CMPTHEIRCODE, @Query) - 1 - LEN(ADTOWN))
        ) -- making sure that the value of CMPTHEIRCODE comes after ADTOWN
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Radu. As soon as I get a second I will try your suggestions. Will let you know.

Comment: @cocojiambo Have you had a chance to check if this runs faster?

Comment: it does come back [pretty quick, but it returns no results no matter what I enter. Trying to debug it and see what might be wrong. Will let you know if I succeed. Thank you for the follow-up.

Comment: @cocojiambo Please let me know what the problem was, maybe I can tweak my query. You can try initially just by replacing the `WHERE` clause in your query with my suggestion. I hope I haven't changed anything in the logic by moving the `JOIN`s to `EXISTS`.

Comment: No @Radu is not working. I tried with just the `WHERE` clause and it does not seem to bring back anything.